# How do I get my money

Tags: blockchain, lost-transactions

I made a transaction on the mining fee of this collector bot and I never got the money though even though it says I did I payed and it seems that  there is some proof that they have paid some others but I wonder if since I never knew And so I didn't add the invoice part into the Blockchain can I still add it and have my fee I've already paid Credit so I can have my money

Comment: I think you have been scammed. Mining fees and collector bots are typical phrases used by criminals a

Comment: you don't. This is like saying: I gave $500 to a strange man on the street, he didn't give me $5000, how do I get it back?